# Android: get text from top screen

Tags: android, sdk

Is there a way to get text from the current top screen in the device?
I want to analyzed the current activity's text in a service that runs in the background (with the user permission of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the screen shot from background using service .

Use tesseract for android to extract text from the image.